# Does the Artificer's Homunculus Servant infusion have any tool proficiencies?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, proficiency, artificer-infusions

The artificer's [Infuse Item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#InfuseItem-1131631) feature (TCoE, p. 9; E:RftLW, p. 57) grants access to a number of infusion options, one of which is the [Homunculus Servant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#HomunculusServant) (TCoE, p. 21; E:RftLW, p. 62).

I'm just trying to find out whether the Homunculus Servant I create has, for example, tool proficiencies to help me creating magic items.

Comment: Welcome to the stack! If you haven't already, please consider taking the [tour]. Happy gaming

Comment: I've added the the [dnd-5e] tag since you linked to the 5e artificer.

Answer (score 7):

#### No. The servant's proficiencies are Perception and Stealth.

The Homunculus Servant has no tool proficiencies. If it did, they would be listed in the infusion description or the servant's stat block, but none are listed. The only proficiencies it has are:

> **Skills** Perception +0 plus PB × 2, Stealth +2 plus PB

Where PB here is the artificer's proficiency bonus.

Comment: Ok... but can it be teached?

Comment: @Rakiden Rules as written, no it cannot. There are optional rules for learning new proficiencies during downtime, but those generally apply to player characters, and then, only at the DM's discretion.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov is incredibly fast and accurate!